# Interpretation of an expression for a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I have a twice continuusly differentiable function $a(x,y)$ of two variables defined for $x \leq y$. It is known that this function is decreasing in $x$, is increasing in $y$, and that $\dfrac{\partial^2 a(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} \geq 0$.

Is there a way to interpet the expression 
$$(y-x)\dfrac{\partial^2 a(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}$$ 
geometrically?